# How to create a conditional argument if one or more items are selected from a selectbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

If I have the following selectbox:

```
<select id="a1" multiple>
<option>Apple</option>
<option>Banana</option>
<option>Carrot</option>
<option>Dates</option>
<option>Eggs</option>
<option>French fries</option>
</select>
```

What is the proper way to write a conditional `if` / `else` statement such that certain functions are executed only if some items are selected?

Meaning:
if Apple or Banana selected, then `if` condition #1 is met and code fires
but if Carrot or Dates or Eggs selected, then `if` condition #2 is met and different code fires
 etc.

EDIT: I guess I used the items in this array as an example, but the most useable construct would peg the condition to the selected index (or indices), not necessarily just to the string values. That way, any selectbox could use the conditional argument, irrespective of the values therein.

Comment: add a eventlistener on the option and check the text, or add additional html value like `data-name="banana"`?

Comment: you want the logic for conditions or code for accessing values?

Comment: you can add a change event handler to the select event and then add the `if` conditions there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use a map, of relevant indices to relevant functions to be called on those indices, for example:

```
function functionOne() {
    console.log('functionOne called');
}

function functionTwo() {
    console.log('functionTwo called');
}

var functionMap = {
    '0-1-2': function(){
        functionOne();
    },
    '4-5': function(){
        functionTwo();
    }
};

$('select').change(function () {
    var valueString = $(this).find('option:selected').map(function () {
        return $(this).index();
    }).get().join('-');
    if (functionMap.hasOwnProperty(valueString)) {
        functionMap[valueString]();
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/uAQXJ/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
  - [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
  - [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
  - [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

Answer (score 0):

## How aboot this?

http://jsfiddle.net/gZSBa/

```
$('#a1').change(function(){
    if($('#a1').val() == 'Carrot' ||  $('#a1').val() == 'Bannana'){
        alert('condition #1');
    }
});
```